# Are there any good public gRPC test API endpoints for learning?

Tags: grpc

Are there any public gRPC test/demo API endpoints that I can use for experimentation while learning gRPC?

The only one I have found is grpc.postman-echo.com

There are tons of public REST/GraphQL APIs, but I find it hard to find public gRPC endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but...

I think this is an interesting question as it is somewhat surprising that there aren't more generic (e.g. `HelloWorld` and Health Checking) services available as public endpoints.

One reason for this may be the need to have either protobuf (schema) sources or generated client for specific services but, per the above, if they are generic services, this shouldn't be as much of an issue.

Google publishes many|most of its services as gRPC and their protos are enumerated in the [`googleapis`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) repo [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google).

If you have Google credentials/project, you can use Google's protos to interact with its gRPC services. I blogged about this [Access Google services using gRPC](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/230314/).

I'm not aware of others.